# Is it possible to delete all rows in a subform by clicking a button in the form?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I would like to delete rows in a table where the table is a sub-from. Is this possible? How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use **DAO**. Very fast and automatic requery:

```
Private Sub DeleteButton_Click()

    Dim Records As DAO.Recordset

    Set Records = Me!NameOfYourSubformCONTROL.Form.RecordsetClone
    If Records.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Records.MoveFirst
        While Not Records.EOF
            Records.Delete
            Records.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    Records.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: The name of my table in the subform is tblMultipleDataEnter and the name of the form is FrmIFMultipleRecords. I added this and still didn't work. What would be the solution?

Private Sub DeleteButton_Click()

    Dim Records As DAO.Recordset

    Set Records = Me!tblMultipleDataEnterCONTROL.Form.RecordsetClone
    If Records.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Records.MoveFirst
        While Not Records.EOF
            Records.Delete
            Records.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    Records.Close

End Sub

Comment: Because these are those not to use. Use the name of the subform control.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly - execute an appropriate SQL `delete` query to clear all records from the table constituting the Record Source for the subform as part of the `On Click` event handler for your button, e.g.:

```vb
Private Sub YourButton_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "delete from YourSubFormTable"
End Sub
```

After deleting the data, you'll need to requery the subform which you can do by invoking the 'requery' method of the form object:

```vb
Private Sub YourButton_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "delete from YourSubFormTable"
    YourSubForm.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: ...and don't forget to requery the subform after deleting

Comment: **DO NOT DO THIS**! OP asked to delete all records in the `subform` not from the entire table. It is entirely possible, parent and sub forms use the same table! Please add a `where condition`

Comment: This actually works fine. Just want to know how to requery after deleting the data

Comment: @Vivek I have updated my answer to demonstrate how to requery the subform.